# ASP.NET MVC retrieving route to controller, action and parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC how can I generate a URL to a specific controller and action along with other parameters. The RedirectToAction allows me to redirect, but I would like to retrieve this URL instead from within my controller.

I tried using:

```
Url.Action("Page", "Administrator", New With {.page = _currentPage})
```

But that returned a link like /Administrator/Page?page=2 whereas I was hoping to retrieve something like /Administrator/Page/2

I've searched countless forums and I'm sure there is something around for this, but I cannot find it for the life of me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do your routes look like?  The standard route expects an id as the third parameter.  If you haven't changed your routes, try using:

```
Url.Action( "Page", "Administrator", New With { id = _currentPage } )
```

Comment: Agreed. It looks like this is why.